# Kafka Connect JDBC sink to Oracle task FAILED

Tags: oracle, jdbc, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

I am trying to sink data from Kafka avro topic to an existing Oracle database table I created beforehand.
I run Kafka Connect in distributed mode (3 workers).
When I submit a new connector through REST, it creates a connector, a new task, but the task immediately fails.
Can't understand why? Below are the task error and my configs.

**Task Error**

```
{"state":"FAILED","trace":"org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Exiting WorkerSinkTask due to unrecoverable exception.
at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.deliverMessages(WorkerSinkTask.java:457)
at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.poll(WorkerSinkTask.java:251)
at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.iteration(WorkerSinkTask.java:180)
at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.execute(WorkerSinkTask.java:148)
at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:146)
at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:190)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)","id":0,"worker_id":"kafka_host02:8083"}
```

**Kafka Connect config**

```
bootstrap.servers=kafka_host01:9092,kafka_host02:9092,kafka_host03:9092
group.id=connect-cluster-00
key.converter=io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter
key.converter.schema.registry.url=http://kafka_host01:8081
value.converter=io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter
value.converter.schema.registry.url=http://kafka_host01:8081
key.converter.schemas.enable=true
value.converter.schemas.enable=true
internal.key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
internal.value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
internal.key.converter.schemas.enable=false
internal.value.converter.schemas.enable=false
offset.storage.topic=connect-offsets
offset.storage.replication.factor=3
config.storage.topic=connect-configs
config.storage.replication.factor=3
status.storage.topic=connect-status
status.storage.replication.factor=3
offset.flush.interval.ms=10000
rest.port=8083
```

**Connector submit command**

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data '{"name": "heat-predict-ora-sink", "config": {"connector.class":"io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnector", "tasks.max":"1", "topics":"MY-TEST-02_topic", "connection.user":"scott", "connection.password":"tiger", "connection.url":"jdbc:oracle:thin:@orahost.localdomain:1521:orcl", "key.converter":"io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter", "key.converter.schema.registry.url":"http://localhost:8081", "value.converter":"io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter", "value.converter.schema.registry.url":"http://localhost:8081", "insert.mode":"insert", "batch.size":"0", "table.name.format":"TEST.MY_TABLE_IN", "pk.mode":"none", "pk.fields":"none" }}' http://localhost:8083/connectors
```

Please tell me any ideas why it behaves so?

Comment: Are there any other errors in the connect log? does this work if you run it as a single worker in distributed mode?

Comment: I started connect-distributed on a single worker and found that the root problem was it couldn't find ojdbc8.jar, I put it into confluent/share/java/kafka-connect-jdbc folder and it helped.

Comment: But there still another problem - now I see the error in connect log about SID. Literally it says me - ORA-12505, TNS:listener does not currently know of SID given in connect descriptor. But I got tnsnames.ora on the host and I am able to connect to the SID with the sqlplus utility. May be I should copy tnsnames.ora somewhere?

Comment: Well I solved that issue :))) by changing ":" to "/" symbol in connect string for jdbc. Now I found next trouble, I see error "Table ABC.DATA_IN is missing and auto-creation is disabled". But again in sqlplus i can connect and make a select from it

Comment: I found similar problem another guy has faced - https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-connect-jdbc/issues/246 It shows up that Kafka Connect cannot understand which schema in RDMBS to use. How to solve that?

Answer (score 1):

Based on https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-connect-jdbc/issues/221 I would suggest that you connect to Oracle as the user of the Schema to which you want to write data, rather than specifying `schema.table`

Answer (score 0):

Finally managed to write into RDBMS when I allowed a table to be auto-created by the Kafka Connect user in its own schema. It is strange that field names in the new table are in quotes, but it is not a stopper. Thanks everyone who tried to help with the answer!